# Trouble with Node JS promises

Tags: javascript, node.js

I cannot find a solution to why this function returns before my message array is updated with the necessary values.

```js
var calculateDistance = function (message, cLongitude, cLatitude, cSessionID) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

    distance.key = options.apiKey;
    distance.units('metric');

    var origins = [];
    origins.push(cLatitude + ',' + cLongitude);

    message.forEach(function (obj) {
      obj.sessionId = cSessionID;
      var destinations = [];
      destinations.push(obj.geoLocation.latitude + ',' + obj.geoLocation.longitude);

      distance.matrix(origins, destinations, function (err, distances) {
        if (err) {
          return console.log(err);
        }
        if (!distances) {
          return console.log('no distances');
        }
        if (distances.status == 'OK') {
          for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < destinations.length; j++) {
              var origin = distances.origin_addresses[i];
              var destination = distances.destination_addresses[j];
              if (distances.rows[0].elements[j].status == 'OK') {
                var distance = distances.rows[i].elements[j].distance.text;
                console.log('Distance from ' + origin + ' to ' + destination + ' is ' + distance);
                obj.distance = distance;
              } else {
                console.log(destination + ' is not reachable by land from ' + origin);
                obj.distance = 'N/A';
              }
            }
          }
        }
      });

    });

    return resolve(message);
  });
}
```

Could someone point out to me what i am doing wrong here.

Regards
Jimmy

Answer (score 1):

```
 var async = require('async');
 var calculateDistance = function (message, cLongitude, cLatitude, cSessionID) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        distance.key = options.apiKey;
        distance.units('metric');

        var origins = [];
        origins.push(cLatitude + ',' + cLongitude);

        async.each(message, function(obj, callback) {
          obj.sessionId = cSessionID;
          var destinations = [];
          destinations.push(obj.geoLocation.latitude + ',' + obj.geoLocation.longitude);

          distance.matrix(origins, destinations, function (err, distances) {
            if (err) {
              callback(err);
            }
            if (!distances) {
              callback('no distances');
            }
            if (distances.status == 'OK') {
              for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < destinations.length; j++) {
                  var origin = distances.origin_addresses[i];
                  var destination = distances.destination_addresses[j];
                  if (distances.rows[0].elements[j].status == 'OK') {
                    var distance = distances.rows[i].elements[j].distance.text;
                    console.log('Distance from ' + origin + ' to ' + destination + ' is ' + distance);
                    obj.distance = distance;
                  } else {
                    console.log(destination + ' is not reachable by land from ' + origin);
                    obj.distance = 'N/A';
                  }
                }
              }
              callback(null);
            }
            });
          },function(err){
             if(err){
               return reject(err);
          }else{
              return resolve(message);
                }
         });
    });
};
```

Comment: Are you returning resolve every time crazy ..that's wrong

Comment: sorry have't saw the foreach. now it should be ok.

Comment: Hi and thanks pointing out where i was thinking wrong. Just a question. Where do i define the mainCallback function ?

Comment: see the latest edit. I forgot you were using promise. So I change it to resolve or reject.

Comment: Actually .. it never seems to enter the distance.matrix block. If i put a console.log() in there it never prints anything.

Comment: if the message is an empty array then it will not go under the async each block. Can you check if the message is a non empty array.

Comment: It is a non-empty array. The array contains result from a Mongoose find() command.

Comment: Then it should get inside the async each block and I do not know what you are doing with distance.matrix function but it should call it. Still can you check if it is going inside the async each block?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your `distance.matrix(origins, destinations, callback )`is asynchronous . In above code distance.matrix method is getting pushed to event loop and continues it's execution and before that method callbacks gets executed `resolve(message)`   is returned .

Answer (score 0):

You need to read up on promises.  It looks to me as if you are thinking of promises as magical way to set up a callback.  "Magic" tends to mean "something I don't need to understand."  In this case that's not true.

That executor function of yours (that is the function which begins with 'function(resolve,reject)') should set up one asynchronous request.  If, as is normal, the request has a callback you put the 'resolve' and 'reject' in the callback.  The result will be a promise object which has methods 'then' and 'catch' where your post-request processing goes.

Since you want to fill up a matrix with the results of a lot of async requests, you will need to read about 'Promise.all' so you can react when all of them have resolved.

Comment: I read up on Promises and Async. I'm a traditional C and Java programmer so it took awhile for me to get used to this asynch programming way of thinking. But now i begin to understand it. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: If you are looking for more to read, you might consider a short ebook I wrote:  https://www.amazon.com/Javascript-Promises-Clarified-Adrian-Zimmer-ebook/dp/B01MZ6WYHJ/